# SQL Server Isolation Levels - Repeatable Read

Tags: sql-server, isolation-level

I'm having problems getting my head round why this is happening.  Pretty sure I understand the theory, but something else must be going on that I don't see.

Table A has the following schema:

```
ID [Primary Key]
Name
Type [Foreign Key]
```

SprocA sets Isolation Level to Repeatable Read, and Selects rows from Table A that have `Type=1`.  It also updates these rows.

SprocB selects rows from Table A that have `Type=2`.

Now given that these are completely different rowsets, if I execute both at the same time (and put `WAITFOR` calls to slow it down), SprocB doesn't complete until SprocA.

I know it's to do with the query on Type, as if I select based on the Primary ID then it allows concurrent access to the table.

Anyone shed any light?

Cheers

Comment: Are you certain that no database modifications (even by triggers) are performed during the execution of SprocA and SprocB?

Comment: Yep, absolutely sure there's no triggers.

Comment: How long does the UPDATE take to perform? Also, are there transactions involved--either through BEGIN TRANSACTION/COMMIT, or through some application connection setting? (Got sidetracked for days once by a rogue setting of SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS...)

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server uses indexes to do range locks (which is what repeatable reads often use) so if you don't have index on Type perhaps it locks entire table...

Comment: Sorry, I forgot a crucial bit of information - SprocA will update those rows.

Answer (score 1):

With Repeatable Read set for the isolation level, you will hold a shared lock on all data you read until the transaction completes.  That is until you COMMIT or ROLLBACK.

This will lower the concurrency of your application's access to this data.  So if your first procedure SELECTS from table then calls a WAITFOR then SELECTS again etc within a transaction you will hold the shared lock the entire time until you commit the transaction or the process completes.

If this is a test procedure you are working with try added a COMMIT after each select and see if that helps the second procedure to run concurrently.

Good luck!

Kevin

Comment: That's fine, but the problem I don't see is why should SprocB have a problem reading rows that aren't touched by SprocA?

Comment: Database usually offer different types of locking schemes which can be configure in the DB setup.  Apart from Table locks which lock the entire table you have row level locking which I think you assume is happening here and data page level locking which locks a data page of X rows.  X might be 10 rows for example depending of the size of the data pages etc.  But if you are locking a data page and not a single row then the other procedure maybe trying to access a row which is in the locked data page.  Does that help at all?  Cheers Kevin

Comment: Sorry just saw you comment about the update below from stored proc A.  Then I would assume the lock is promoted to an exclusive lock from a shared lock with the update.  So if it is a data page and not a row that is locked then you might be locking X rows and not the single you are working on.

Answer (score 0):

The thing to remember is that the locked rows are black boxes to the other process.

You know that SprocA is just reading for type = 1 and that SprocbB is just reading for type = 2.

However, SprocB does not know what SprocA is going to do to those records.  Before the transaction is completed, SprocA may update all of the records to type = 2.  In that case, SprocB would be working incorrectly if it did not wait for SprocA to complete.

Maintaining concurrency when performing range locks / bulk changes is tough.